# How to secure JavaScript-enabled login page without TLS

Tags: authentication, web-browser, iot

I am involved in an IoT project with single pager web UI. Unfortunately, as it was discovered in a hard way, TLS stack is not viable on the selected platform. The alternatives I've found for securing the XMLHTTPRequest traffic relay on integrity and authenticity of the bootstrap/login page. Is it safe to assume that in local networks attackers **will not be able** to intercept a request for login page from a browser to a device and send a hijacked login page instead with malicious JavaScript?

Comment: TLS stack not available? Sounds like that platform is worse than useless - its a liability.

Comment: Which platform doesn't support TLS?

Comment: ESP8266 - although it has TLS but it is not practically usable for the needs of the projects due to much higher lags and quick RAM fragmentation

Comment: You would still have the wifi password protecting the communication in a local situation. most device-based lan pages (ip cams, routers, etc) are served without https, though that's beginning to change...

Comment: Yes, that's a good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it safe to assume that in local networks attackers **will not be able** to intercept a request for login page from a browser to a device and send a hijacked login page instead with malicious JavaScript?

No, you cannot assume that unless the connection itself is reliably protected (e.g. an inaccessible UTP cable or already authenticated WiFi connection).